# xmgrace .agr File Commands

Tags: file, code-generation, xmgrace

I am attempting to write a program that will generate .agr files that can be loaded and manipulated in xmgrace. I've dissected an example file that has the kind of formatting I'm looking for, but I'm not 100% sure what every line does. A lot of the commands are self-explanatory for the most part, but is there a guide somewhere I can use to reference some of the more obscure lines like `@reference date 0`, `@default sformat "%.8g"`, `@r0 off`, etc.?

I've looked around the grace website in both the user and developer sections as well as googling individual lines without much luck. All I'm looking for is basically a `man` page of xmgrace .agr files. The more low-level details, the better.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you have already looked through all of the [official documentation](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/) for Grace/xmgrace. This documentation doesn't give much information about the internals of the .agr files that xmgrace creates.

I have found in the past that creating your own files and studying them in a text editor is a good way to learn what each line does, but as you said it is not always possible to decipher everything.

A project that is doing something similar to you is [pygrace](https://github.com/pygrace).
Maybe if you look at the pygrace source code it will give you some further clues to fill of the gaps in your existing knowledge.